# Parameterize a SELECT ROWCOUNT sql statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have a a few SQL queries which I am converting them from using parameters instead concatenations for SQL injection prevention.

Below is a SELECT query which is parameter-ed:

```
string loggedinuser = (User.Identity.Name);

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [UserTable] where [" + DropDownList1.Text + "] like @searchtb AND [LoggedInUser] LIKE @userlog";
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("searchtb", "%" + searchTB.Text + "%");
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("userlog", "%" + loggedinuser+ "%");
```

The above sql query searches for records base on the user's input in a search textbox and return results which matches the search input and username in the database.

---

I have another SQL query which is also a *SELECT* statement. However, this time it does not use `SqlDataSource`, but using `cmd` instead. Thus I need some help in converting the SQL statement below to parameter form:

```
string loggedinuser = (User.Identity.Name);

        string stmt = "SET ROWCOUNT 1 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MP.dbo.UserTable where [" + DropDownList1.Text + "] like '%" + searchTB.Text + "%' AND [LoggedInUser] LIKE '%"+loggedinuser +"%'";
        int count = 0;

        using (SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
        {
                thisConnection.Open();
                count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
                thisConnection.Close();
        }
```

This SQL query searches for number of records that the user is trying to search base on his search input and username. And if `countuser` returns a 0 value, I will prompt the user after that.

---

I need help in converting the 2nd SQL statement into parameter form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MP.dbo.UserTable where [" + DropDownList1.Text + "] 
                    like @searchTb AND [LoggedInUser] LIKE  @loggedinuser";

    int count = 0;

    using (SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
    {
            cmdCount.Parameters.Add("@searchTb",SqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value="%" + searchTB.Text + "%"; 
            cmdCount.Parameters.Add("@loggedinuser",SqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value="%" + loggedinuser + "%"; 

            thisConnection.Open();
            count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
            thisConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: @AVD is it possible to parameter my DropDownList1? i tried adding a parameter to it but it didn't work.

Comment: @RUiHAO - No, Sql can't have parameters on fieldnames or tablenames.

Answer (score 0):

Using stored procedures is your best bet, but if you cannot use them, this code should work:

```
SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(
"SELECT au_lname, au_fname FROM Authors WHERE au_id = @au_id", conn);
SQLParameter parm = myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@au_id", 
                        SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);
Parm.Value = Login.Text;
```

This is from the MSDN article on SQL injection.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx